# xCode CGRectMake will only draw a square?

Tags: ios, xcode, cgrectmake

I am trying to draw a simple rectangle shaped label but when I run my code, the app always draws a square? Here is my code.

```
UILabel *box =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,100,20)];
box.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:box];
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: it draws red rectangle for me. maybe your base view is square.

Comment: can you add image here?

Answer (score 0):

Check your superview autoresize mask.  It happens when superview autoresize mask is flexible for width for itself and its subviews.